# https prevent image hotlinking and allow from https

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https, virtualhost

I have this virtualhost setup in Apache 2.2.15/CentOS 6.9.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /gallery
    ServerName image.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

In this /gallry folder, I have many images files stored.

And I have /gallery/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://([^.]+\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://([^.]+\.)?example\.com.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g?|png|gif|ico|pdf|flv|swf|gz)$ - [F]
```

But the problem is that if I access the site from http://www.example.com, I can see the images as expected and denied from other sites. But When I access it from https://www.example.com, access is denied,too.

I need to access the http://image.example.com/images from https://www.example.com. I have been searching for the answer but I could not find it yet.

Any help will be appreciated.